# why for small value of $x$, $e^{x}-1$ is close to $x$?

Tags: calculus

why for small value of $x$, $e^{x}-1$ is very close to $x$?

Suddenly, I wrote following code and I surprised. The question is why this two  functions are close for small value of $x$.

```
beta1<-structure(c(0.00581299965594357, 0.00398749971786833, 0.00555549997749978, 
0.0039364999682459), .Dim = 4L)
beta2<-structure(c(-1.7105e-07, -8.1175e-08, -4.7495e-07, -1.3675e-07
 ), .Dim = 4L)

>  exp(beta1)-1
[1] 0.005829928 0.003995460 0.005570960 0.003944258
>     beta1
[1] 0.0058130 0.0039875 0.0055555 0.0039365
>  exp(beta2)-1
[1] -1.710500e-07 -8.117500e-08 -4.749499e-07 -1.367500e-07
>     beta2
[1] -1.7105e-07 -8.1175e-08 -4.7495e-07 -1.3675e-07
```

Comment: Hint: look at the Taylor expansion of $e^x$.

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$

Comment: Um, because at $0$ they intersect?

Comment: Also $\sin x$ is close to $x$ when $x$ is small.  You need radians not degrees for this to work.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Intersection alone is not sufficient for two functions to be close near zero, you need derivatives here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know about derivatives? For a function $f$ around a point $x$, the derivative $f'(x)=\frac{df}{dx}$ is the *slope of the tangent* to the graph of the function at the point $(x, f(x))$.

Now, take the function $f(x)=e^x$. It goes through the point $(0, e^0)=(0,1)$. Recall that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$ (again). Thus, the slope of the tangent to the graph of $f$ at the point $(0,1)$ is $f'(0)=e^0=1$. Thus, the tangent of $f(x)=e^x$ at the point $(0,1)$ is the line $y=x+1$. Now, "translate" everything "down" by $1$: the tangent to the graph of the function $y=e^x-1$, which goes through $(0,0)$, is $y=x$.

*That* is why the lines $y=e^x-1$ and $y=x$ are so close to each other: the latter is the tangent to the former at the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: What does this have to do with derivatives? Isn't it a consequence of the simple fact that $x,e^{x}-1$ intersect at $0$? $x,2x$ also get pretty close for small values of $x$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I guess you are right in some sense. However, this would not produce the same observation by the OP. If $f$ and $g$ merely intersect at $x$ (i.e. $f(x)=g(x)$) but $f'(x)\ne g'(x)$, then the difference $f(x+h)-g(x+h)\sim Ch$ where $C=f'(x)-g'(x)$. This means the difference is of the same order of magnitude as $h$. Now look at the OP's figures, e.g. exp(beta2)-1 vs. beta2: obviously the difference is a *lot* smaller than $h$ (in this case beta2), rather than being of the same order of magnitude as beta2. This happens *precisely* because those derivatives cancel out.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri ... It is true, for example,  that $e^x-1$ and $-2x$ are close to each other for $x$ near $0$, because both are close to $0$.  But Massoud noticed that $e^x-1$ and $x$ are much closer to each other  than that!  This is one of the elementary properties of derivative.

Comment: Yes, the data does indicate that their difference is $O(h^2)$.